# Python condensed if statements

Tags: python, string, function, loops, for-loop

I am experimenting with **how to condense if statements** within my code. I have a project I am working on that has several "if" statements (too many to keep track of) and want to figure out a way to condense them. Obviously this involves a for loop, but I am having trouble adding additional operations within this loop.

I came up with the **following working example** to demonstrate my issue:

```
num=6

if_options = [num==5, num==6]

for i in range(len(if_options)):
    if if_options[i]:
        print(num)
```

I want to add an additional piece to the code. This additional piece will execute an operation within the if statement. See **following non-working example** as a framework for what I am trying to accomplish:

```
num=6

if_options = [num==5, num==6]
operations = [num=num+1, num=num-1]

for i in range(len(if_options)):
    if if_options[i]:
        operations[i]
        print(num)
```

For whatever reason, it will not execute the *operation* portion of the code and fails with a syntax error. It does not let me declare the command "num=num+1" (without quotes) within a list, however this declaration is necessary for executing the command. I feel like I am missing one little thing and it should be an easy fix. **Thank you in advance!!**

Comment: Can yıou explain what the purpose of this? Maybe there is a better way to do what you are aiming to to.

Comment: I don't think your "working example" works in quite the way you think it does.  When you evaluated the expression `[num==5, num==6]`, the comparisons were performed *at that moment in time* - what you're assigning to `if_options` is simply the list `[False, True]`.  So even if your expression for `operations` was syntactically valid, it would be pointless, as all of the operations would have *already been performed*.

Comment: @jasonharper is `operations` line even valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the operations are evaluated when you create the list of them. You want to write them as strings, and then `eval`/`exec` them in the loop. I will assume you also want the conditions evaluated in the loop.

```
num = 6

if_options = ['num==5', 'num==6']
operations = ['num=num+1', 'num=num-1']

for i in range(len(if_options)):
    if eval(if_options[i]):
        exec(operations[i])
        print(num)
```

Comment: Sorry, I corrected `eval` to `exec` when running the operations.

Comment: This is generally not what you want, however. You should probably actually write the code in your function, and do refactoring some other way.

Comment: Maybe having two function one for increasing and one for decreasing would be a better idea. You can add a reference of them to a list and call them in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

why not functions?

```
def check(inp):
    #you can do some logic and type checking here
    return type(inp)==int # for example, or return arguments to pass to the operatiins

def operation(inp2):
    if inp2: # check if true or not empty, as an example
        #do some operations

# and then you do something like

for x in input_of_things:
    operation( check( x ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lambda expressions too.

```py
num = 6
if_option_checks = [lambda x: x == 5, lambda x: x == 6]
operations = [lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x - 1]
for check, operation in zip(if_option_checks, operations):
    if check(num):
        num = operation(num)
```

Or you could use dictionaries and lambda expressions

```py
num = 6
if_option_checks = {"add": lambda x: x == 5, "sub": lambda x: x == 6}
operations = {"add": lambda x: x + 1, "sub": lambda x: x - 1}
for key, check in if_option_checks.items():
    if check(num):
        num = operations[key](num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a switch statement structure could help.

First define a switch function:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c: v in c
```

Then use is in a one-iteration for loop that yields a case function for the switch value:

```
for case in switch(num):

    if case(5):
        num = num + 1
        break

    if case(6):
        num = num - 1
        break

    ...
```